# How do you create a semi-transparent background for a UIView?

Tags: xcode, uiview

I am creating a UIView containing some text that partially covers a UIImageView. I want the user to be able to read the text and still maintain a perspective on the image underneath. I have tried setting the background color to [UIColor clearColor], but then the background is totally transparent and it is hard to read the text depending upon the image colors.

If I lower the view.alpha=0.5 the whole view including the text is partially transparent. What I'd like is to maintain the text and reduce the transparency of the background partially, allowing the image to show through.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think what you mean is you want the backgroundColor of your UIView to be semi transparent? If you want white/transparent use this:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:myWhiteFloat alpha:myAlphaFloat];
```

else if you want it to be another color use the general UIColor method: `+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`

Comment: I tried the following "  self.summaryViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.2];" and it did not have any effect. There are a number of subviews in the summaryViewController.view. Would that have any effect?

Comment: I got it to work. Interestingly, I had to add the command to the viewDidLoad of the summaryViewController rather than in it's parent view controller.

Answer (score 39):

### OPTION 1 - USING STORYBOARDS

For those who have their view in a storyboard or .xib, you simply do it in interface builder by selecting the option "Clear Color" for the Background of the view in the Utilities Pane (the pane on the right). "Clear Color" will give the view a completely transparent background.

[image: See screenshot]

If you need a background color that is partially transparent, select the desired background color with the color picker and use the Opacity slider at the bottom to set the transparency.

[image: opacity slider to arrange transparency of the background colour of your view]

---

### OPTION 2 - USING COLOR ASSETS (AND STORYBOARDS)

Another very useful option is to add colors to your `.xcassets` library, so that you can use the same color easily in different views. You can make these colors (semi-)transparent as well, here's how:

1. Open your `.xcassets` library
2. Add a Color Set

[image: Add a Color Set to your xcassets library]

3. Give it a useful name and select the color thumbnail

[image: Give it a useful name and select the color thumbnail you'd like to adjust/create]

4. In the `Attributes Inspector` you can then change the color and use the slider to adjust its opacity

[image: Create the color and use the Opacity slider to adjust it's transparency]

5. Go back to your storyboard and select the view you need this transparent background color
6. In the `Background` option of in the `Attributes Inspector` you can now select the Color you added to your `.xcassets` library. This is very useful if you have multiple views across your app using the same background.

[image: You can now select the color you just created in your storyboard]

In code you can access the colors from your Color Assets using:

**SWIFT (UIColor):** `UIColor(named: "DP Textfield")`

**SWIFTUI (Color):** `Color("DP Textfield")`

Answer (score 7):

This will work.

```
myView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7f];
```

Answer (score 5):

Eventually you already have a color so you could use `.colorWithAlphaComponent` like this:

```
let exampleColor = UIColor.blackColor()
overlayView.backgroundColor = exampleColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4+ :

Black translucent view:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use:

```
myView.alpha = myAlphaFloat;
myView.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: This sets the entire view and it's contents. Jesse's answer sets the backgroundColor.

Comment: NO, this is what question asker said he did NOT want to do, because he is trying to make the text 100% opaque - only the *background color* is desired to be semi-transparent.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin C#, at this time, the visual storyboard does not have the "opacity" slider of Xcode's storyboard [mentioned by Bocaxica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16080990/199364).

If you set `BackgroundColor` for View `nameOfView` in storyboard, then in your view controller's `ViewDidLoad`, add this line to set alpha:

```
nameOfView.BackgroundColor = nameOfView.BackgroundColor.ColorWithAlpha( 0.7f );  // A value between 0 and 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3+

white half transparent:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
```

or black half transparent:

```
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
```