# Popping up subview

Tags: iphone, ios

How to animate only the frame ie. the subview and not the entire view and how to add segmented control buttons inside that subview? I want the subview to popup when i click a button, but the subview should be translucent in such a way that the parent view behind is visible.

Comment: What code have you tried? What problems are you running into?

Comment: I'm seeing about three separate questions here.

Comment: You can add UIView as subview on your mainView, and make it transparent. Also add close button to remove it from mainView.

Comment: Check the following links. This should resolve your issues. [SubView slide in animation, iphone][1] [how-do-you-create-a-transparent-background-for-a-uiview][2] [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343915/subview-slide-in-animation-iphone [2]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655093/how-do-you-create-a-transparent-background-for-a-uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take UIView global if you want to add and remove this also add subview in your this view

```
        UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:sel.view.frame];
        /////== Add your subviews in this tempView
        tempView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
        tempView.alpha = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{
            tempView.alpha = 0.94;
            tempView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
        }];
       tempView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        [self.view addSubview:tempView];
```

**Update :**

First take object of UIView in your .h file like

```
UIView *tempView;
BOOL isOpen;
```

in `viewWillDidLoad:` method just define this

```
isOpen = NO;
```

and after use this code

```
-(IBAction)btnSetting_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    if (isOpen) {
        isOpen = NO;
         [tempView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else {
        isOpen = YES;
        tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        /////== Add your subviews in this tempView
        [tempView addSubview:yourSegControl];
        tempView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
        tempView.alpha = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{
            tempView.alpha = 0.94;
            tempView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
        }];
        tempView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        [self.view addSubview:tempView];

    }
}
```

i hope this help you..

:)

Comment: It was very useful, thanks. But now i want to add the segmented control buttons inside the popup subview and i also want the pop up to disappear, when i click the settings button again. Can u give me the exact code for all these things? That includes both the interface and implementation part.

Comment: just add the segment control in your PopUpView and set the bool value , when its open set as a yes like isOpen = YES; when again button clicked at that time set as a No like isOpen = NO; , if my answer is useful to you then accept answer or up-vote.. :)

Answer (score 1):

First you make youe `subview` transparent:

```
[subview setAlpha:0.5f];
```

And then add this code before the `addSubView` line:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];          // you can try carious options here
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];    // here too
[animation setDuration:0.3];
[animation setValue:@"Throb" forKey:@"MyAnimationType"];
[subview.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add subview to main View

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height); // Replacing with your dimensions
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:subView];
```

You can make it transparent using

```
[subView setAlpha:0.2];
```

You can add any UI Controls to this view.

Hope this will help you out.